# How can I display content in a model object in template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How can I display `country`, and `city` of an `UserType1` object in template?

```
class UserType1(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,parent_link=True,primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def get_country(self):
        return self.country

    def get_city(self):
        return self.city
```

I have the below in views.py

```
def profile(request,userid):
    basic_info = User.objects.get(pk=int(userid))
    profile = UserType1.objects.filter(user=int(userid))
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    return render(request, template_name, {'userid':userid,'basic_info':basic_info, 'profile':profile})
```

and the following in template

```
{% if profile %}
    {{ profile.get_city }}
    {{ profile.city }} 
{% endif %}
```

Neither worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing properties on a queryset, rather than a model instance, as you haven't called `get` on `UserType1`.

Try:

```
profile = UserType1.objects.get(user=int(userid))
```

---

As an aside though, a small change would simplify your code a little:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
...
basic_info = User.objects.get(pk=int(userid))
profile = basic_info.profile
```